# Value mapping in Grafana Heatmap

Tags: grafana

Is there a way to do Value mappings in Grafana for "Heatmap" Pannels? I see it for "Time Series" but not for "Heatmap".

I have several "null" entries in my table which are displayed as if they were 0 (light yellow), which is wrong and should be colored black (or simply excluded).[image]

I use Grafana v9.1.6

Comment: Have you tried "Hide cells with values <="?